# What is the dimension of cosmological constant $\Lambda$

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, astrophysics, cosmological-constant

I came across two forms of the Friedmann equation. Those are as follows:

$$H^2=\frac{8\pi G \epsilon}{3c^2}-\frac{\kappa c^2}{R_{0}^2 a^2}+\frac{\Lambda}{3}\tag{1}$$
$$H^2=\frac{8\pi G \rho}{3}-\frac{k c^2}{ a^2}+\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}\tag{2}$$

In Eq.(1) the dimension of cosmological constant is $time^{-2}$. In Eq.(2) the dimension cosmological constant is $length^{-2}$. The first two terms on RHS in both equations are equivalent from the definition of the corresponding terms. But for the third term, considering the constant $c^2$ included along with $\Lambda$ in Eq.(2) will give Eq.(1). Am I correct? If so, is there no fixed dimension for cosmological constant?

Comment: This question was already answered at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/711586/the-unit-of-the-cosmological-constant

Comment: @Yukterez Does that mean both forms of equations are correct and the actual unit of cosmological constant is $m^{-2}$?

Comment: Yes, if you look at the Einstein field equations $\Lambda g_{\mu \nu}+...=\rm T_{\mu \nu} 8 \pi G/c^4$ it must have the units 1 over area