# Approximation for Newton's formula for gravity as modified by the expansion of the universe?

Tags: general-relativity, newtonian-gravity, space-expansion, cosmological-constant

Newton's formula for the gravitational force between two objects is

$$F = -\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}.$$

Assuming the force is due to the exchange of gravitons and that gravitons are affected by the expansion of the universe in the same way as photons, can I simply modify the formula so it behaves in the same way as radiation pressure?

$$F = -\left(1-\frac {Hr} c\right)\frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$$

where $H$ is the Hubble constant and $c$ is the speed of light

I suppose it also assumes that the force is small and that the objects are not gravitationally bound.  Is this a reasonable first order approximation?

[Edit 3] I appreciate the answers, but I don't feel comfortable with them. A uniform constant expansion of the universe gives rise to an acceleration of $H^2r$ between any two points separated by $r$. This is because $r$ increases with time and so the recession velocity Hr also increases with time. But this does not cause any acceleration with respect to the CMB, for example, and is not a function of either mass and cannot be included as a correction to Newtons formula for force.

If we define force as mass times acceleration with respect to the CMB, then I'd like to suggest

$$F = - \left (1-\frac {Hr} c  \right )^4 \frac {Gm_1m_2}{r^2} $$

with the first order correction being approximately $$ 4 \frac H c \frac {Gm_1m_2} r $$

This expression is simply by analogy with the [radiation pressure from a distant black body](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/727544/how-does-apparent-brightness-or-stellar-magnitude-change-with-distance-in-an-e/727554?).

Comment: See e.g. [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/531426).

Comment: It looks like $(1-(Hr/c)^3)$ would work better than  $(1-Hr/c)^3$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, I noticed that too, but I don't know how to justify it.

Answer (score 3):

starting with this metric
\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{G}=\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} B \left( r \right) {c}^{2}&0&0&0
\\  0&-A \left( r \right) &0&0\\  0&0
&-{r}^{2}&0\\  0&0&0&-{r}^{2} \left( \sin \left(
\theta \right)  \right) ^{2}\end {array} \right] 
\end{align*}
you obtain from the geodetics equations and the first integrals
\begin{align*}
 &r^2\,\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=l=\text{constant}\\
 &B(r)\frac{dt}{d\tau}=\frac{1}{c}\,f=\text{constant}
\end{align*}
that (conservation of the energy)
\begin{align*}
  &A(r)\left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2+\frac{l^2}{r^2}-\frac{f^2}{B(r)}=-\epsilon=\text{constant}\tag 1
\end{align*}
with $~\epsilon=c^2~$ (from  $~ds^2~$ ) and with  the Schwarzschild metric
\begin{align*}
 &B(r)=\frac{1}{A(r)}= 1-\frac{2\,a}{r}\quad,a=\frac{G\,M}{c^2}\quad\Rightarrow
\end{align*}
equation (1)
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{dr}{d\tau}\right)^2+U(r)=\frac{f^2-\epsilon}{2}=\text{constant}\\
 &U(r)=-\frac{G\,M}{r}+\frac{l^2}{2\,r^2}-\frac{G\,M\,l^2}{c^2\,r^3}
\end{align*}
thus the Newton correction  is $~-\frac{G\,M\,l^2}{c^2\,r^3}$

---

with the cosmological constant $~ \Lambda$

$$B(r)\mapsto B(r)-\Lambda\,\frac{r^2}{3}$$

thus the Newton correction is now

$$-\frac{G\,M\,l^2}{c^2\,r^3}-\Lambda\,\frac{r^2}{6}$$

**Force**

with $~l=\frac Lm~$

$$F=-m\,\frac{dU}{d\tau}=
{\frac {{L}^{2}}{m{r}^{3}}}-3\,{\frac {G\,M{L}^{2}}{m{c}^{2}{r}^{4}}}-{
\frac {m\,M\,G}{{r}^{2}}}+\frac 13\,m\,r\Lambda
$$

**De-Sitter  solution**

with $~H^2=\frac {\Lambda}{ 3}\quad\Rightarrow$

$$F=
{\frac {{L}^{2}}{m{r}^{3}}}-3\,{\frac {G\,M{L}^{2}}{m{c}^{2}{r}^{4}}}\underbrace{-{
\frac {m\,M\,G}{{r}^{2}}}+m\,r\,H^2}_{=-(1-x)\frac{m\,M\,G}{r^2}}
$$

thus

$$x=\frac{r^3\,H^2}{M\,G}$$

**Friedmann equation for materiel dominate cosmos**  ($~c=1~$)
\begin{align*}
& \dot{r}^2-\frac{K_m}{r}-\frac{1}{3}\Lambda\,r^2=-k\tag 1
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align*}
 &K_m=\frac{8\,\pi\,G}{3}\rho_m\,r^3=\text{constant}
\end{align*}
multiply equation (1) with $~\frac M2~$ you obtain the energy
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{M}{2}\dot{r}^2\underbrace{-\frac{G\,M^2}{r}-\frac{M}{2}\,\frac{1}{3}\Lambda\,r^2}_{U(r)}=-\frac{M}{2}\,k=\text{constant}
\end{align*}
where
\begin{align*}
 &M=\frac{4\,\pi}{3}\rho_m\,r^3
\end{align*}

thus the force is (with $~\Lambda=3\,H^2~$)
\begin{align*}
  &F=-\frac{G\,M^2}{r^2}+M\,H^2\,r
\end{align*}

Comment: thanks, how do interpret the constant 'l' (el)?

Comment: This is the geodetic equation for $~\phi~$ with $~\theta=\pi/2~$

${\frac {d^{2}}{d{\tau}^{2}}}\phi \left( \tau \right) +2\,{\frac {
 \left( {\frac {d}{d\tau}}r \left( \tau \right)  \right) {\frac {d}{d
\tau}}\phi \left( \tau \right) }{r \left( \tau \right) }}
=0~$ from here you obtain that $~r^2\,\dot\phi=\text{constant}=l~$ $~,l=\frac Lm~$ where L is the magnitude om the angular momentum

Comment: (I assume L=0)  It seems difficult to call this correction a gravitational force if it does not depend on M.  PS. It looks like your H is already normalized against c to make the units work?   PPS. clever formatting

Comment: @RogerWood you are right factor $~c^2~$ is wrong !

Comment: I see the recent edit, thanks.  While an H^2r term describes the acceleration in any distance r due to the expansion, it doesn't result in any real acceleration (with respect to the CMB, for example).

Comment: @RogerWood the EOM is $~M\ddot r=F~,\quad, c=1~$ so the unit of $~H^2\,r~$  is acceleration unit ,but c is missing some where

Answer (score 2):

The gravitational force doesn't redshift. It Lorentz contracts:

[image]

This image shows the electric field, but the (relativistic) gravitational field behaves similarly. The gravitational field of an object moving away from you is effectively weaker, but so is that of an object moving toward you,

Perhaps you could try to capture that in a version of the force law that includes a dependence on velocity as well as position, but if you want to go that far in the pursuit of correctness, then I think you should also use the retarded position and velocity. If you do everything correctly, you will end up with linearized GR.

$H$ shouldn't be in the formula, because the strength of gravity doesn't depend on it. $Hr$ may be a good approximation to an object's recessional velocity, but since you're writing a per-object force law (where $r$ is the distance between two particular objects), you should use the actual velocity of those objects, not an approximation to it.

I think the best quasi-Newtonian force law is the one in [the Q&A that J.G. linked in a comment](/q/531426). You can derive the second Friedmann equation with $p=0$ from it, and since $p\approx 0$ for most of the universe's history, the Newtonian cosmology is a pretty good approximation to ΛCDM.

Comment: that's helpful, but I'm not sure I can follow through.  It does seem that gravitational force will behave very differently to radiation force.

Comment: @RogerWood Yes, the 1/r² force is very different from radiation pressure (same with electromagnetism).

Comment: do electrostatics and 'gravitostatics' show the same weak dependence on expansion and electromagnetics (luminance) and gravitomagnetics (gravitational waves) show the same stronger dependence on expansion?

Answer (score 2):

There is an exact solution where (in $G=c=1$ units, which everyone should be using for doing general relativity) you replace $1-2M/r$ with $1-2M/r - \frac{1}{3}\Lambda r^{2}$, which will give you $T_{ab} = \Lambda g_{ab}$ (you can verify by computing the Ricci curvature of the above metric directly), and so we can think of as "asymptotically (anti) de Sitter Schwarzschild".

Since for de Sitter in 3+1 dimensions, $a(t)= a_{0}e^{t\sqrt{\Lambda/3} }$, we have $H = \sqrt{\Lambda/3}$, and at least for this case, a better ansatz would be to generalize Newton by $F_{{\rm on\;} m_{1}} = Gm_{1}\frac{m_{2}}{r^{2}} - 2m_{1}H^{2} r$ rather than the multiplicative rule you took.

Comment: your constant C is [c²/3](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1053#p1053) where c is the speed of light

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer thanks, but how can the correction not depend on the two masses and how does the new term, 2cHr, end up with units of force?

Comment: @RogerWood: because it's a "repulsive force arising from the expansion of the universe" and has nothing to do with the two masses, and just describes the tendency of two objects to hubble expand away from each other no matter what else is happening.  I did realize that there was a slight error (the force should be proportional to the mass of the object that the force is acting on, so I added that correction)

Comment: @Jim: you're right, there was a square root factor in converting the hubble constant (units 1/s) back from the cosmological constant (units 1/m^2).  It is fixed above now.

Comment: also in de Sitter or our late universe H is not √Λ but H=√(Λ/3), and if you don't set anything to 1 then H=c√(Λ/3), see https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/712084/24093

Comment: @Yukterez.  Fine.  The key point, though, is that the multiplicative rule above is wrong.  Constant factors fixed.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer I don't feel comfortable with any of the answers. Surely the correction has to be symmetric in m1 and m2.  In the existing answers, the correction persists even if the distant mass is non-existent (zero).

Comment: @RogerWood: expanding universes don't conserve momentum.  Ignore their attraction due to gravity.  If I put the two masses a distance $a_{0}D$ apart, the distance between them at some later time will be $aD$, and the recession velocity doesn't depend on their mass, just on the distance to them.  You can't make conservation of momentum work in this situation, ad thus, newton's third law is not valid and there is no reason to expect symmetry in the two masses.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer Maybe I'm getting a glimmer of understanding. Two points 'r' apart are separating at the rate of Hr. After t seconds, they are r+Hrt apart and separating at a rate of H(r+Hrt). This corresponds to an acceleration of [H(r+Hrt)-Hr]/t = H^2r.  It is the separation 'r' that accelerating and we can divvy this up appropriately between m1 and m2. This gives [m2/(m1+m2)]H^2r for the acceleration of m1 and the apparent force on m1 would be [m1m2/(m1+m2)]H^2r.  But this has nothing to do with gravity.

Comment: I don't know if I agree with the statement "this has nothing to do with gravity".  The cosmological expansion is a gravitational effect that is not present in Minkowski space.  Also, if you initially started out at the midpoint of the two masses, they would both reced away with equal velocities, and you wouldn't have the center of mass factors.  The center of mass of the system is not a fixed point.  Momentum is not conserved in this system.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer I'm still looking for an answer to the question.  If I replace 'expansion of the universe' with a simple recession velocity, is that a solved problem?

Comment: @RogerWood I don't understand how the above is not an answer to your question.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer H^2r is the rate at which r accelerates. But m1.H^2r is not a force. It doesn't depend on the other mass and it doesn't produce an acceleration of m1 with respect to the CMB.

Comment: @RogerWood I thought the premise of this question is "taking a Newtonian approximation of GR", in which case, the CMB frame is a non-inertial frame that is invalid for Newtonian analysis.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer doesn't CMB provide an absolute reference for an object's velocity and thus its acceleration?

Comment: @RogerWood: in the Einstein picture, sure, but in the Newtonian picture, it's an expanding reference frame that will violate Newton's third law and is non-inertial.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer I'm not sure that changes anything. I can in theory measure an absolute acceleration with respect to the CMB and I'd like to know how that changes when a distant mass is introduced.

Comment: @RogerWood: idk, there's an exact solution to einstein's equation above that has a black hole and an expanding background.  If you want to ignore terms, fine, but all of the physics you're asking about is included there.  I don't get what else you could want.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer It's clear that the correction term should disappear if the distant mass disappears.  I'm guessing that your formulation describes the motion of a test particle with respect to the distant mass assuming that the distant mass is stationary and not accelerating and is at the origin of the coordinate system.

Comment: @RogerWood: if you're unhappy with some property of the coordinate system, you're free to transform to some other coordinate system.  It will remain an exact solution to Einstein's equation describing a black hole in a de Sitter background.

Comment: @Jerry Schirmer Transform to an inertial coordinate system at the position of the test particle in the expanding universe with a black hole of zero mass.  Then introduce a black hole of finite mass.  That correction term will be absent.

Comment: @RogerWood: having a black hole and not having a black hole are two topologically different states, and you cannot continuously change between them.  I don't even know what the operation "Introduce a black hole of finite mass" means.

Comment: why do you expect there to be some term that is proportional to $M\Lambda$?

Comment: @JerrySchirmer I don't see anything in the equation that prevents the black hole mass approaching zero or approaching infinity.  I expect the correction term to depend on the black hole mass.

Comment: @RogerWood: the above answer provides an exact solution of Einstein's equation with a cosmology and a black hole.  It's not a "correction" or an "approximation", it is an exact solution.  What else do you want?  I am legitimately not understanding what the problem is.

Comment: @JerrySchirmer (I appreciate your patience with me)  I have no doubt it's a correct solution but it assumes the black hole is fixed and answers the question how is the test particle moving.  My question is about the interaction with the black hole mass, M.  If I take the difference between a very small black hole mass and a very large black hole mass, the answer is just the usual Newtonian acceleration of GM/r^2.

Comment: @RogerWood: the two body problem in general relativity is likely a chaotic problem, and even if not chatoic, it is definitely extremely complex.  Even without the cosmology, there are only approximations for analyzing, say, a system of two black holes orbiting each other.  You get the Newtonian law in the non-relativistic limit by looking at the motion of a test particle where a central mass is large, and back-approximating.  This is the same process taken above.  A more rigorous approach would be to turn the post-newtonian approximation crank, but the result would be the same.